# From userDefaults.standard.sring(forKey "name").components(seperatedby: " ") I want to make a List

Tags: swift, listview, swiftui, swiftui-list

From `userDefaults.standard.sring(forKey "name").components(seperatedby: " ")` I want to make a List in a View (SwiftUI List).
`List { userDefaults.standard.string(forKey "name").components(seperatedby: " ")[1] userDefaults.standard.string(forKey "name").components(seperatedby: " ")[2] ... }`
with a variable length of `userDefaults.standard.string(forKey "name").components(seperatedby: " "`

I tried for...in and while but it can't be in a View

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to fetch data from the `UserDefaults` and after that build a List. Here you can find more info about `List` component in SwiftUI: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-create-a-list-of-dynamic-items

Also you can't place `String` inside the List, you should wrap it by `Text` component (here is info about this component https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text)

So this is how it should look like in your case:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    // Extracting data from UserDefaults
    let names = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "name")?.components(separatedBy: " ") ?? []
    
    var body: some View {
        // List received array of names by first parameter
        List(names, id:\.self) { name in
            Text(name) // <-- Here you wrap your string inside UI component
        }
    }
}
```

But you should know that this list won't be dynamic. If something will be changed inside `UserDefaults`, your view won't be updated. For making it dynamic you should create an `ObservableObject` model for managing your data. You can read more about this protocol on this link: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-observedobject-to-manage-state-from-external-objects